# Encryption + EUF-CMA => SUF-CMA

Tags: encryption, signature

Does there exist a proof (paper reference welcome) that if a signature scheme is EUF-CMA, and the signatures are always encrypted, then the resulting signature scheme is SUF-CMA?
That is: let SIG be an EUF-CMA signature scheme. Then SIG' is defined as follows:

1. s = SIG(secret key, message)
2. c = ENC(K, s) where ENC is a symmetric-key encryption scheme

The SIG' signature is c. K is known only to "honest" verifiers. K is unknown to adversaries against the SIG' signature scheme.

If SIG is EUF-CMA secure and ENC provides confidentiality, then SIG' is SUF-CMA secure.

Comment: A good way to settle the status of a proposition is exhibiting a counterexample. Update: for the "symmetric-key encryption scheme (that) provides confidentiality" in a counterexample, I suggest AES-CTR with random IV.

Comment: Your security notions for signatures are very precise, while the one of encryption are more vague. One approach to answer the question is to try to be precise with the definition of “confidentiality” and see whether it achieves the desired goal or not.

Comment: This can't be answered without further specification: Are the secret key and K identical? What ENC security do you mean, CPA, CCA (CCA1, CCA2)? Does an adversary get both oracles or a combined oracle? What are EUF and SUF? Some use wEUF (weak existential unforgeability and sEUF (strong EUF). What exactly is the role of the "honest" verifier?

Comment: In your envisioned scenario the signer and verifier seem to share a symmetric secret key and security is only required against external adversaries (i.e., not against the verifier) In that case, why a signature at all?